Nodal analysis with matrices

We have the following circuit. Our goal is to determine the . The straightforward method taught to us is to first: turn the voltage source to a current source and second: set the nodes:

The Op-Amp is ideal, so the current flowing in inverting and non-inverting outputs is zero. The output current is I0. The current source is
when using conductances: We can now form the following matrix:

Where the output voltage is the same as U_2 in the matrix. U_1 = U_3 due to Op-Amp being ideal then we just add up column 1 and 3: We can also remove the row representing I_0 after addition due to it canceling out; We end up with such matrix:

My answer is wrong. My question, and my question only, is: what did I do wrong with the approach. The choice of solving method shouldn't be a problem to my knowledge. I know this circuit can be solved with other methods, but I can't move on without learning what I did wrong with this approach method.
Thank you in advance!

Study of network topology. Analysis by the method of node voltages:


The method above works fine, if you calculate the conductance of (1/3)R correctly => G = 1/R = 1/(1/3) = 3 Siemens. Then, you do the steps like mentioned in the post and you end up with the correct answer.
